# Margin-top pushing down parent but overflow:hidden is not helping

Tags: html, css

Adding margin-top to one of my nested divs causes the surrounding divs to be pushed down. I've seen multiple answers on other questions (overflow:hidden/auto, adding a border, adding a margin/padding of 1px) but none seem to be helping.
This is the basic setup:

```css
.added-margin {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.div-three {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-one">
  <div class="div-two">
    <div class="div-three">
      <div class="other-div"></div>
      <div class="added-margin">This has a margin of 50px and contains other divs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rugo. What are you trying to achieve. I see you have added those as flex continers :) Actually, I do not see surrounding divs being pushed how. https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/WNjaZYe 
I have just added some data in first div

Comment: what do you expect to happen if you use a margin? margin adding white-space. As such it should be expected that it moves other elements...

Comment: Hey @ImranRafiqRather I basically have a header and inside the div with the "added-margin" class are the buttons like the account-button, cart-button, etc. I want the buttons to be displayed at the same level as the search bar of the header but this is causing my header to get more space at the top as well instead of just pushing the buttons down

Comment: Dear @Rugo.  If you could add your full code in the same Codepen link that I have shared and also add the CSS. We'll have more idea about what is happening and why ? 
Meanwhile, I need to go for prayers.
Will check that once I do my prayers.

Thank you

Comment: @Rugo If you can create a codepen.io project (or use my above link in the first comment) , add your code and we can then try to help you out. 
This way the requirement is not clear. :)

Answer (score -1):

overflow will be considered, once the height of the 'div' is added

```css
.added-margin {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.div-three {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;

    height : 30px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-one">
    <div class="div-two">
        <div class="div-three">
            <div class="other-div"></div>
            <div class="added-margin">This has a margin of 50px and contains other divs</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```